# Sharing images using Activityviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios6

How can i share images from imagescrollview using ActivityViewController.

Below is the code for displaying images in imagescrollview

```
UIScrollView *imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
   imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 61;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
 [imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

Trying to share images from imagescrollview using activityviewcontroller but in the very first statement getting message in red that expected expression

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[UIImage imageNamed:]imageView];// **getting message in red expected expression**
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePrint ];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
[activityViewController release];
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Store the images in an array first in the forLoop where you are adding the images to scrollview,then

```
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];  //imageArray is the nsmutablearray in which you shall store the images
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning image to object of Array and Your Syntax is also wrong..
So That's why you are getting **getting message in red expected expression** this..

Try this code instead of your code

```
NSMutableArray * activityItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [[activityItems addObject:imageView];
}
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePrint ];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
[activityViewController release];
```

Comment: actually imagescrollview code in viewdidload method and on the imagescrollview have a activityviewcontroller button UIBarButtonItem *actionButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                         target:self
                                         action:@selector(ActionSheet2:)];
        
and in actionsheet2 method have to show activityviewcontroller. So from viewdidload method how to read images to share in activityviewcontroller actionsheet2 method